# Difference between ： and :?

Tags: javascript, symbols, html-escape-characters

Can somebody tell me the difference between two in html. i was found this ： in url but when i'm connecting with request in node js, the respond is **ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS**.

Which is confusing because symbols are like : (colon).

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You should escape them.

Comment: `:` should be encoded to `%3A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) to encode the special character. It assumes that the input is a complete URI that might have some characters which need encoding in it.

`encodeURI(url)`

> This function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ #
>   (Use `encodeURIComponent(`) to encode these characters).
>
> Tip: Use the `decodeURI()` function to decode an encoded URI.